# Can a web page trust a browser extension based on its extension-id alone?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser

A browser extension published on Chrome Web Store has its unique extension-id. However, the manifest->"key" field that yielded the extension-id can be extracted for any extension (e.g. through [link](https://robwu.nl/crxviewer/). Using this "key", a user can locally create an altered version of the published extension but with the same id by loading unpacked & modified version of the code.

[Passing message](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-sendMessage) to an extension from other extensions or web pages is done by using extension-id as the trusted identifier. If the user benefits from fooling these reliant web pages or extensions, he will be able to do so.

There isn't a way for the web page to know the [installType](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/management/#type-ExtensionInstallType) of extension without relying on the extension itself.

I hoped that the "key" field wouldn't be publicly visible to anyone but the uploader(developer) but that evidently is not the case.
My questions are:

1. Is there a way for web page to know that the extension they're communicating with is an authentic web-store published one ?
2. Is similar problem present for extensions of other browsers too ?

Please let me know if there is any further detail I can provide. Thanks

Comment: 1) No. 2) Yes - in those that are based on Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following workaround, which fit my use case.
The browser extension exposes some files like manifest.json, service-worker.js, wasm as web-accessible-resource to some specific website, which acts as an auditor. This auditor website will fetch and check the integrity of these scripts and configs when necessary to ensure the specific extension is not modified. This fits my use case because the user uses the extension only in the presence of the auditor site.

chrome.runtime.getURL(path_of_resource) can not be invoked by the website but the returned path value has a format (`chrome-extension://${extensionID}/path_of_resource`) that helps bypass the problem.